# Tortoise svn create http repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i want to move my local repository to http but i couldn't create or move repository. How can i do it? I am using tortoise svn.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i don't understand "move local repo to http", http is a protocol, http deamon/server can serve files over network (using http protocol).

So I understand that you'd like to have your svn repo content available over http, am i right?
Tortoise is just svn repo client.
So you have to have, repository server.
ie. apache + svn modules.

Here I've googled some tut:
http://www.howtoforge.com/apache_subversion_repository

Edit:

create root repo on your ie. linux machine using:

> svnadmin create

If you want HTTP use apache server
manual http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html
I won't copy it, since it's step by step howto.

Simpler solution without apache (then you'd use URL's and its internal protocol)
set up your server using:

> svnserve -d -r /usr/local/repositories

now you could write some access rights on your repo in config files
and access:

> svn checkout
>   svn://host.example.com/project1

Complete manual [man](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html)
I won't copy it, since it's step by step howto.

Comment: yes i'd like to have my repo available over http and i want to be able to use it anywhere. so i have a domain and i want to create a repository in it. can i do it myself or is there anything to do server side?

Answer (score 1):

If the remote machine is a Microsft machine try VisualSVN Server.
If you are the only user and don't want to use a server, try it like described [here](http://invalidlogic.com/2006/12/06/using-subversion-without-a-subversion-server/)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

See my question on SF: https://serverfault.com/questions/96113/read-only-svn-on-apache2-under-windows there you will find example of Apache configs to setup SVN repo over http